# Nodeclipse - How to exclude `bower_components` at any path from jshint-eclipse validation

Tags: eclipse, bower, jshint, nodeclipse

What should be config to exclude any path that has `bower_components` from jshint-eclipse validation

I tried several, included what said in  [#64](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse/issues/64)

> For example, they use `/**/` as path segment wildcard, while we currently use `//`.

Current [`.settings/com.eclipsesource.jshint.ui.prefs` for Nodeclipse](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/templates/common-templates/.settings/com.eclipsesource.jshint.ui.prefs)

`eclipse.preferences.version=1
excluded=//*.json\://bower_components//*\:node_lib//*\:node_modules//*
included=//*.jjs\://*.js\://*.jshintrc\://*.mjs\://*.njs\://*.pjs\://*.vjs
projectSpecificOptions=true`

That is `//bower_components//*` for exclusion,
but I still got libraries under `app\bower_components` validated by jshint-eclipse.

Also asked as [#101](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse/issues/101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//bower_components//*` is enough. just  remove previous warning from Problems view.